# Linear programming constraint "x >= c or x = 0"

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to express a linear program having a variable that can only be greater or equal than a constant c or equal to 0. The range ]0; c[ being unallowed.

Do you know a way to express this constraint in a linear program, in a way that it can be solved using an unmodified simplex implementation ?

For example this constraint :
x1 >= 4 or x1 = 0.

Typical relation between all constraints in a linear program is AND.
Here this is an OR between two constraints.

Note: I need to solve problems having multiple variables like this in a computationally efficient way.

Comment: take a look at this, it may work http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-01.html. Try something like, if x1 < c then x1 = 0 else x1 >= c

Comment: Hi, your link refers to integer programming and an unmodified simplex implementation does not handle integer programming

Comment: you can solve both problems x1 >= 4 and x1 = 0 and then compare the results.

Comment: sorry I should have mentionned that I have not just one but a bunch of variable like this and I cannot solve the problem for every combination, performance-wise this is combinatory prohibitive to solve the problem 2^numberOfVariableLikeThis times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mathematical program with the constraints you've defined cannot be represented as a linear program and therefore cannot be solved using an unmodified simplex implementation. The reasoning is simple enough -- the feasible set for a linear program must be convex. A set like `{x = 0 or x >= 2}` is not convex because it contains points `x=0` and `x=2` but not `x=1`.

As a result, you'll be forced to use other mathematical programming techniques; the one that comes to mind would be mixed integer linear programming (MILP). For each variable `x_i` with a constraint of the form `x_i = 0 or x_i >= c_i` you would define auxiliary variable `y_i`, along with the following constraints:

```
x_i >= c_iy_i
x_i <= My_i
y_i binary
```

If `y_i=0`, then the constraints are `x_i >= 0; x_i <= 0`, meaning `x_i=0`. If `y_i=1`, then the constraints are `x_i >= c_i, x_i <= M`. You should set `M` to a sufficiently large value for your problem, but be careful not to set `M` too large, as this will make your problem harder to solve.

Whether or not this is computationally tractable depends on the size and structure of your mathematical program as well as the quality of the solver you're using. You have many options for a MILP solver; for instance in R you could use the `lpSolve`, `lpSolveAPI`, or `Rglpk` libraries, or in MATLAB you could use the `intlinprog` function. In general cplex and gurobi are considered the best MILP solvers, but both are commercial and would require a license.

Comment: How can I express that kind of constraints with glpk?