# How to constrain a linear program so that all continuous variables have a minimum positive value but can also be 0

Tags: linear-programming

I would like to solve a problem that has 5 continuous variables using a linear program.  For one of the constraints, each variable can be 0, but if it is not, then it must be above 0.3.  In other words, the variable must be positive and must not be between 0 and 0.3.  What equations can I use to express this constraint?

Constraints:
x1 = 0 or x1 >=0.3 
...
x5 = 0 or x5 >=0.3

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I think that this has been answered here already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449959/linear-programming-constraint-x-c-or-x-0?rq=1

Comment: Such a variable is called a semi-continuous variable. Many (but not all) MIP solvers have direct support for this.

Comment: Great, thank you both!